# Return angular ngView to nothing

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have routes in my Angular script like so:

```
app.config(function($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider

  .when("/contact", {
    templateUrl : "views/contact.html",
    controller : "GeneralCtrl"
  });

});
```

Now I have links that will happily take me to the contact page like so:

```
<a href="#contact">Contact</a>
<div ng-view></div>
```

Now I have another link that I want to remove the view so the site goes back to looking as it did before the user clicked on the contact link. The following doesn't work and refreshes the page:

```
<a href="#">Home</a>
```

How do I get this to work? If I declare it in the routes config, what would I put as template and controller? It has none. I need it to apply the `ng-leave` classes to the view as well.
I am using Angular 1.3.

Comment: i think, you are trying "back" button behaiour. if yes, you can simply do <a href="javascript:window.history.back()">Home</a> (or) you are trying to load home page then you should call <a href="/">Home</a> and write router config based on this.

Comment: "what would I put as template and controller? It has none." - You just answered the question yourself.

Comment: @Asik no I don't want a back button. The 'home' view has no view loaded, then when the user clicks on 'contact' it loads the contact view. The home link should then change the route to home again (which has no view loaded)

Comment: @zeroflagL I'm not sure what you mean. Could you explain?

Comment: You can add a route that neither sets a template nor a controller.

Answer (score 0):

just use $routeProvide.otherwise and use redirectTo property to redirect to your home template

```
app.config(function($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider
  .when("/", {
    templateUrl : 'views/home.html',
    controller : 'HomeController',
   });
  .when("/contact", {
    templateUrl : "views/contact.html",
    controller : "GeneralCtrl"
  })
  .otherwise({ redirectTo: '/' });

});
```

**EDIT**

```
<a href="#contact" ng-click="setClass = true;">Contacts</a>
<p ng-class="{'ng-leave': setClass}">Im the element that'll have ng-leave class</p>
<ng-view>
   here is the view that I load
</ng-view>
```

Comment: This seems to reload the page (like a total refresh) which does remove the view, but I can't have a page refresh as I need `.ng-leave` classes to work.

Comment: I think maybe you misunderstand. The 'home' route has no view. It shouldn't load a template at all. It just shows all the code outside of the ng-view.

Comment: angular js doesn't reload the page (i.e. refresh) .. it just switches the view and controller inside ng-view.. 

see edit

Comment: Kindly make a plunkr so I may see what's actually going on there :)

Comment: I couldn't get this working in Plunkr but I downgraded my version of Angular from 1.3 to 1.2 which fixed the problem. `<a href="#"></a>` now removes the view.